# What is the fastest way to convert html to pdf using JS or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf

I have a long table for about ~100.000 rows which is generated dynamically (technically it can be divs).
It's needed to export this html data into pdf.

I have tried to use **html2pdf.js**. But when it is over 5000 rows it begins to work very slow and exported pdf has huge size. I think it is due to saving html as image and then inserting it into document.

Have tried **html2pdf.php** Also works slow from over 500 rows already has troubles, but document has very good size.

Have tried **html-pdf** with node js. Works much faster then previous 2, but there is one limitation. Node js script is on server and when there more then one client, performance is distributed between all client and performance decreases dramatically.

I am in search of library which will convert very long html table into pdf document for acceptable amount of time.

**My needs can be described as:**

**1**) The script can run in browser (Javascript) an should be fast enough in order not to make user wait for ages.

**2**) The script can run on server using PHP/Node js, but here should be considered that at the same time several users can request pdf.

**3**) May be there are some other solutions for examples on Java or Python which will run on Linux server that could be easily triggered from browser?

**Options 1 or 2 are the most desirable.**

Thanks!

Comment: _“and when there more then one client, performance is distributed between all client”_ - well yeah, what else could possibly happen? Your server is not magically going to clone itself, just because a second request came in.

Comment: i am very happy with `wkhtmltopdf` check it out, in case of performance, you can only try to not generate the actual same list again and load a copy if nothing changed

Comment: Is it necessary to go the extra step of data → HTML → PDF…? Can you not output the data directly as PDF?

Comment: Would a "generation" queue something you'd consider? User requests PDF → request goes into a queue → server handles queue operations → email sent to user with download link when PDF has been generated.

Comment: In case of client side processing it is preferable that the pdf file is immediately downloaded. I also tried to use native methods `printDiv.print();` but it took a lot of time.

Comment: `wkhtmltopdf` will try, thanks

Comment: “and when there more then one client, performance is distributed between all client” - here I was writing about node js. And as far as Node js is single threaded it can't use all cors. And performance is always limited by one core, but not whole CPU. In My case it is about 16% of load. I can use workers for each request, but the library I tried benefits only partially from clustering. When begins process of exporting html to pdf all requests at a time can have only 16% of CPU. If 4 clients, then each script consumes not more 4%.

Comment: @user3828374 can you provide an example of what data is in tables/rows/columns?

Comment: it could from 2 columns till 5-10. Table cells contain numbers (table header contain titles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the comments (which is deleted for some reason) suggested me to try **AutoTable - Table plugin for jsPDF**.
Thank you!
This plugin for js library html2pdf does an amazing job! Works with the speed of light.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend DomPDF if you are using PHP because it's simplicity. 
Here is an example based on their [quickstart example](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#quick-start):

```
// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world'); //complete page DOM goes here

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```

You can find more information on how to install and other examples in their repository: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: Thanks! Have tried. 1000 rows works good, but 10000 rows where generating almost 10mins, and for some reason I didn't get the answer :)